# Get list of firebase entry based on query option

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am using Angular 2 to build a web app. I am trying to retrieve data from firebase when one or more of the condition(s) are met in the child node. For example, below is how my firebase are structured. I want to pick out the entry for the one with approverEmail being approver1@mail.com as well as status being 0 (Both have to be met at the same time).

```
{
  "BugList" : {
    "Company 1" : {
      "-Kbne6WxelgI6Qv9T0eP" : {
        "approverEmail" : "approver1@mail.com",
        "firstName" : "Jack",
        "lastName" : "Daniels",
        "noteToApprover" : "Gooday mate",
        "status" : 0,
      },
      "-Kbne6WxelgI6Qv9T0QP" : {
        "approverEmail" : "approver2@mail.com",
        "firstName" : "Tom",
        "lastName" : "Riddle",
        "noteToApprover" : "Howdy",
        "status" : 1,
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Currently, I am using angularFire2 which has limited amount of information on this topic. This is what I have at the moment and I am stuck

```
forms.service.ts
getPendingApproval() {
    var currentUser: User = this.userService.getCurrentUser();
    const queryList = this.af.database.list('/BugList/' + currentUser.company, {
        query: {
            // email field match currentUser.email && status == 0 
        }
    });
}
```

and in my app.component.ts

```
getList() {
    this.list = this.formsService.getPendingApproval()
  }
```

---

Code for my forms.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class FormsService {

    constructor(private af: AngularFire, private userService: UserService) { }

    saveToFirebase(bug: Bug) {
        const bugRef = this.af.database.list('/BugsList/' + bug.companyName);
        return bugRef.push(timesheet)
    }


    getPendingApproval() {
        var currentUser: User = this.userService.getCurrentUser();
        const queryList = this.af.database.list('/BugsList/' + currentUser.company, {
            query: {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code for service.

Comment: What is the query?

Comment: There is nothing in it at the moment because I dont know the syntax to achieve this unfortunately. Im not even sure if that function is correct at all hence the help

Comment: you should read [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md) before posting a question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its only possible to query one field. (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/305#issuecomment-230936970)

You could filter the second field after receiving the pre-filtered list.

Example for a query:

```js
query: {
  orderByChild: 'email', // field name !
  equalTo: 'test@web.de' // search criteria
}
```

Filtering using a `Subject`:

```js
const filterSubject = new Subject(); // import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
const queryObservable = af.database.list('/items', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'email',
    equalTo: filterSubject
  }
});

// subscribe to changes
queryObservable
   .map(qis => qis.filter(q => q.status == 0)) // FILTER HERE FOR STATUS
   .subscribe(queriedItems => {
      console.log(queriedItems);
   });

// trigger the query
filterSubject.next('test@web.de');

// re-trigger the query!!!
filterSubject.next('huhu@gmail.com');
```

docs: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase, which covers a way to do server-side filtering on two values (yet still only one property) in some cases.

Comment: That's `pure firebase`, not the required `angularfire2`. But good to know! :)

Comment: AngularFire2 is a wrapper around the Firebase JavaScript SDK. The capabilities when it comes to querying multiple values are the same: if you can combine the values into a single property (in the way described in the linked answer), you can filter on them with AngularFire2 too..